# Problem with if on codeigniter 3 function

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, codeigniter

Hello i'm working on a codeigniter 3 project and i need to assign a ticket to different person depeding who is trying to assinging it.

In the next example i want to do this: if the user that has the ID=92 the ticket will be assigned to him, but if the user has the ID=94 the ticket will be assigned to the user with the ID=92(responsable) and he will be saved in another column inside the database (colaborador).

The problem is that the "if" is not working at all, if i log with another user f.e.  the one with the ID=1 it still do all the job.

example:

```
public function assign_user($consultaid, $hash) 
{
    if($hash != $this->security->get_csrf_hash()) {
        $this->template->error(lang("error_6"));
    }
    $consultaid = intval($consultaid);
    $consulta = $this->consultas_model->get_consulta($consultaid);
    if($consulta->num_rows() == 0) {
        $this->template->error(lang("error_84"));
    }
    $consulta = $consulta->row();
    $usuario = $this->user->info->ID;

    if($usuario = 92) {
        $this->consultas_model->actualizar_consulta($consultaid, array(
        "responsable" => "92",
    )
);

    } 

    if($usuario = 94) {
        $this->consultas_model->actualizar_consulta($consultaid, array(
        "responsable" => "92",
        "colaborador" => "94",
    )
);

    }   

    $this->consultas_model->agregar_historia(array(
        "usuarioid" => $this->user->info->ID,
        "mensaje" => $this->user->info->username . " " . lang("ctn_661"),
        "fecha" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        "timestamp" => time(),
        "consultaid" => $consultaid
    )
);

    if($consulta->status == '0'){
        $uData = ['status'=>1];
        $this->db->where('ID', $consulta->ID);
        $this->db->update('consultas', $uData);
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata("globalmsg", lang("success_56"));
    redirect(site_url("consultas/ver/" . $consulta->ID));
}
```

I hope it was clear at all

Thanks

Comment: `if ($usuario = 94)` should have two `=`. `=` - assigning value; `==` - comparison

Comment: make a == or === and try in if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($usuario = 94) {
```

One `=` means that you are assigning this variable this value and it will be always true, you need to use comparison operators `==` or `===`

Comment: my bad :) i figured out late but you are right! thanks

Comment: no worries :) good luck!